# Pasar Array con numeros a SqlServer, split e insertar los datos

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure, sql-server-2014

Aqui les traigo mi problema.
[image: Error Al ejecutar Procedure]

Utilizo SqlServer 2014 y VisualStudio 2015

Tengo un Objeto llamado CashRegister el cual tiene estos atributos:

```
public class CashRegister
{
    private static CashRegister CashRegisterInstance;

    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DgiSucCode { get; set; }
    public bool? ForceMoneyControl { get; set; }
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
    public Entities.Printer Printer { get; set; }
    public Entities.Localidad Localidad { get; set; }
    public List<Entities.User> User { get; set; }
    public List<Entities.DocumentModel> DocumentModel { get; set; }
}
```

Como ven tengo 2 Listados dentro de el, User y DocumentModel lo que quiero es pasar un Array de Id de Cada uno para poder Insertarlos en una Tabla con el mismo Procedure.

Mi Persistencia:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Create or Update a User Data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Entities.CashRegister Save(Entities.CashRegister Data)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCashRegisters_SaveUpdate", Connection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", Data.Id));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", Data.Name));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", Data.Description));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DgiSucCode", Data.DgiSucCode));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ForceMoneyControl", Data.ForceMoneyControl));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Active", Data.Active));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocalidadId", Data.Localidad.Id));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DefaultPrinterID", Data.Printer.id));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Users", this.ConvertToStringArray(Data.User)));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DocumentModel", this.ConvertToStringArray(Data.DocumentModel)));

                //Agregado para recibir el error en caso de que halla
                SqlParameter RuturnValue = new SqlParameter("@RequestStatus", SqlDbType.Int);
                RuturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(RuturnValue);
                /// Fin de Agregado
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Data.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
                    }
                }
                int retval = (int)cmd.Parameters["@RequestStatus"].Value;
                Data.Id = retval;
            }

            return Data;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Metodo para Convertir el listado en un String

```
private string ConvertToStringArray(object o)
    {
        List< Entities.DocumentModel> doc = new List<Entities.DocumentModel>();
        List<Entities.User> us = new List<User>();
        string returned = "";
        try
        {
            doc = (List< Entities.DocumentModel>)o;
            var last = doc.Last();
            foreach (var item in doc)
            {
                if (item.Equals(last))
                {
                    returned = returned + (item.Id).ToString();
                }else
                {
                    returned = (item.Id).ToString() + ",";
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            us = (List<Entities.User>)o;
            var last = us.Last();
            foreach (var item in us)
            {
                if (item.Equals(last))
                {
                    returned = returned + (item.Id).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    returned = (item.Id).ToString() + ",";
                }

            }
        }
        return returned;
    }
```

Mi Procedure:

```
 -- Create or Update a Message
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'spCashRegisters_SaveUpdate')
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCashRegisters_SaveUpdate]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCashRegisters_SaveUpdate] (
     @Id int = null
    ,@Name varchar(129) = null
    ,@Description varchar(256) = null
    ,@DefaultPrinterID int = null
    ,@LocalidadId int = null
    ,@DgiSucCode varchar(10) = null
    ,@ForceMoneyControl bit = null
    ,@Active bit = null
    ,@DocumentModel nvarchar(max) = null
    ,@Users nvarchar(max) = null
    ,@RequestStatus int output
)
AS
set @RequestStatus = 1 --Lo seteo en uno en caso de que todo salga bien
If NOT Exists(select top(1) ID from ApplicaAccCS_Max.dbo.Localidades where ID = @LocalidadId )
   BEGIN
      --RAISERROR('Localidad: ingresada no existe: Error en @LocalidadId', 16, 1);
      set @RequestStatus = -2
      return -2; ---Localidad Error = -2
   END
If NOT Exists(select top(1) pri.Id from Printer as pri where pri.Id = @DefaultPrinterID )
   BEGIN
        set @RequestStatus = -4
      --RAISERROR('Impresora: ingresada no existe: Error en @DefaultPrinterID', 16, 1);
      return; ---impresora Error = -4
   END
   If NOT Exists(select top(1) doc.Id from tbDocumentModels as doc where doc.Id = @DocumentModel )
   BEGIN
      --RAISERROR('Documento: ingresado no existe: Error en @@DocumentModelId', 16, 1);
      set @RequestStatus = -5
      return -5; ---Documento Error = -5
   END
BEGIN
    IF @id IS NULL BEGIN
    declare @Id_Ultimo int = 0;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
        begin Transaction
        begin Try
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbCashRegister]
                (
                 [Name]
                ,[Description]
                ,[DefaultPrinterID]
                ,[LocalidadId]
                ,[DgiSucCode]
                ,[ForceMoneyControl]
                ,[Active]
                )
            VALUES
                (
                 @Name
                ,@Description
                ,@DefaultPrinterID
                ,@LocalidadId
                ,@DgiSucCode
                ,@ForceMoneyControl
                ,@Active
                );
            Select @@IDENTITY;
            SELECT @Id_Ultimo = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

            INSERT INTO tbUserByCashRegisters(CashRegisterId, UserId)
            Select @Id_Ultimo
                   ,r.Name
                   from [dbo].[splitstring](@Users) r
                   where Name != ''
            INSERT INTO tbDocumentModelByCashRegisters(DocumentModelId, CashRegisterId)
            Select r.Item
            ,@Id_Ultimo
                   from [dbo].[SplitInts](@DocumentModel, ',') r
                   where Item != ''
            Commit
         End Try
        begin Catch
        rollback
        End Catch
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
        begin Transaction
        begin Try
        UPDATE [dbo].[tbCashRegister]
        SET 
             [Name] = @Name
            ,[Description] = @Description
            ,[DefaultPrinterID] = @DefaultPrinterID
            ,[LocalidadId] = @LocalidadId
            ,[DgiSucCode] = @DgiSucCode
            ,[ForceMoneyControl]= @ForceMoneyControl
            ,[Active]= @Active
        WHERE
             [Id] = @Id;
        Select @Id;
            --UPDATE tbUserByCashRegisters 
            --SET
            --  [UserId] = @UserId
            --  ,[CashRegisterId] = @Id
            --WHERE 
            --  [CashRegisterId] = @Id
            --UPDATE  [dbo].[tbDocumentModelByCashRegisters]
            --SET
            --  [DocumentModelId] = @DocumentModelId
            --  ,[CashRegisterId] = @Id

            --WHERE 
            --  [CashRegisterId] = @Id
            Commit
         End Try
        begin Catch
        rollback
        End Catch
    END
END
GO
```

**Metodos para Split el String:**

Opcion 1:

```
      USE [Applica.Acc]
 GO
 /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[splitstring]    Script Date: 16/02/2018 12:55:08 ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[splitint] ( @stringToSplit nvarchar(MAX) )
 RETURNS
  @returnList TABLE ([id] [int])
 AS
 BEGIN

  DECLARE @id int
  DECLARE @pos INT

  WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
  BEGIN
   SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
   SELECT @id = CAST(SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1) as int)

   INSERT INTO @returnList 
   SELECT @id AS [int]

   SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
  END

  INSERT INTO @returnList
  SELECT @stringToSplit

  RETURN
 END
```

Opcion 2:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
 (
    @List      VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter VARCHAR(255)
 )
 RETURNS TABLE
 AS
   RETURN ( 
   SELECT Item = CONVERT(INT, Item) FROM 
   ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
         FROM 
        ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i) ) AS y
       WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
 GO
```

Comment: Por favor no pongas imagenes de tus errores, si no que copia todo el error en la pregunta. las imagenes se pierden, y no se pueden indexar

Comment: Perfecto, que es lo que exactamente tengo que copiar del error siempre?

Comment: El error lo mas completo posible, e indicar donde se da el mismo, mira [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/) para saber que se necesita pegar.

Answer (score 0):

**El error estaba aqui en el**

```
       --If NOT Exists(select top(1) doc.Id from tbDocumentModels as doc where doc.Id = @DocumentModel )
   --BEGIN
      ----RAISERROR('Documento: ingresado no existe: Error en @@DocumentModelId', 16, 1);
      --set @RequestStatus = -5
      --return -5; ---Documento Error = -5
   --END
BEGIN

select top(1) doc.Id from tbDocumentModels as doc where doc.Id = @DocumentModel
```

estba comparando el string a un campo doc.Id que es un Entero, entonces sqlserver esta parseando tu arraystring "4,5" a un entero "4.5" cosa que no puede darse.

Comente eso y funciono.

Comment: Puedes [publicar y aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Lee aquí [cómo elaborar una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - le será de mucha ayuda a la comunidad. Saludos.